# find max value in a table with his relative ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose to have a Table  person(**ID**,....., n_success,n_fails)

like

```
 ID  n_success   n_fails

 a1      10         20
 a2      15         10
 a3      10         1
```

I want to make a query that will return ID of the person with the maximum n_success/(n_success+n_fails).

example in this case the output I'd like to get is:

```
  a3   0.9090909091
```

I've tried:

```
  select ID,(N_succes/(n_success + n_fails)) 'rate' from person
```

with this query I have each ID with relative success rate

```
  select ID,MAX(N_succes/(n_success + n_fails)) 'rate' from person
```

with this query just 1 row correct rate but uncorrect ID

How can I do?

Comment: Wich RDBM's are you using? Retag to have better visibility and answers.

Comment: You specify that you want the Id corresponding to the maximum value of `n_success/(n_success+n_fails)` and the max value of `n_success/(n_success+n_fails)`, but your example is wrong. You should be showing `a3, 0.9090909091`.

Comment: you're right, I made a mistake, I'm going to correct

Comment: If some of the answer has helped you to solve your problem, check it as the correct one so future visitors can refer to it. But on this case, all are correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, (`n_success` / (`n_success` + `n_fails`)) AS 'Rate' FROM persona
ORDER BY (n_success / (n_success + n_fails)) DESC
```

MySQL

```
SELECT `ID`, (`n_success` / (`n_success` + `n_fails`)) AS 'Rate' FROM `persona`
ORDER BY (`n_success` / (`n_success` + `n_fails`)) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your dialect of SQL, but in T-SQL it would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.ID, p.n_success / (p.n_success + p.n_fails) AS Rate
FROM persona p
ORDER BY p.n_success / (p.n_success + p.n_fails) DESC
```

You can vary as necessary for other dialects (use `LIMIT 1` for MySql and SQLite, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Lot of answers already. Check working code here on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6739/5) with the required output by your last edit.

```
SELECT `ID`, `n_success` 'rate'
  FROM `persona`
 ORDER BY (`n_success` / (`n_success` + `n_fails`)) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, (n_success/(n_success + n_fails)) as rate from person
where (n_success/(n_success + n_fails)) = 
    (select max(n_success/(n_success + n_fails)) from person)
```

Comment: Standard SQL here. No limit/top/order required etc. One row returned - the one you want.